# Symfony Authentification Error at login_check

Tags: security, exception, symfony, doctrine

### Intro

I've been following these two documentation tutorials for Symfony2 Security:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database

### Problem

Now when I try to login at localhost/login, it either brings me back to /login (which is fine) with "bad credentials" or it brings me to /login_check and an error occurs (I haven't found a pattern of when it does what).

### Error

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

> Fatal error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long
>   $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) in
>   C:\wamp\www\minimumCrayon\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException.php
>   on line 25

I've tried looking around for anyone with a similar error, but I'm pretty darn lost.

Edit: Here is my security.yml file

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        WikiRoster\MainBundle\Entity\Account:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administartors:
            entity: { class: AcmeMainBundle:Account}

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: you can attach a `security.yml` file?

Comment: Yep.  We need to see your security.yml file.  Or revert to the default file and then make one change at a time to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I editted my question to include the security.yml file.

Comment: Rebuild your vendors (php composer.phar update) and it will probably solve your problem !

Comment: I ran "php composer.phar update" but i'm still getting the same errors.